# How to make my Tabbar transparent in MAUI App

Tags: maui, android-widget, android-bottomnav, maui-shell

I have used a customShellHandler to make a tabBar in my home screen placed bottom of my screen.  Since I used margin and radius, the background of tab show as white. I wanted to make it transparent to display the content page's color [This is How my page looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZjeO.png)

Here is my AppShell.XAML

```
<TabBar >
     <Tab Title="Add New" >
         <ShellContent
         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AddNewAwake}"
         Route="AddNewAwake" />
     </Tab>
     <Tab Title="Upcoming">
         <ShellContent
         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:UpcomingAwake}"
         Route="UpcomingAwake" />
     </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

---Below is my CustomHandler

```
internal class CustomShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(IShellContext shellContext, ShellItem shellItem)
    : ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(shellContext, shellItem)
{
    private readonly IShellContext shellContext = shellContext;
    public static Color color = Colors.Red;
    public override void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
    {

        base.SetAppearance(bottomView, appearance);
        if (Shell.GetTabBarIsVisible(shellContext.Shell.CurrentPage))
        {
            var backgroundDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
            backgroundDrawable.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
            backgroundDrawable.SetCornerRadius(30);
            backgroundDrawable.SetColor(appearance.EffectiveTabBarBackgroundColor.ToPlatform());

            bottomView.SetBackground(backgroundDrawable);
            var layoutParams = bottomView.LayoutParameters;
            if (layoutParams is ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams)
            {
                const int margin = 30;
                marginLayoutParams.BottomMargin = margin;
                marginLayoutParams.LeftMargin = margin;
                marginLayoutParams.RightMargin = margin;
                bottomView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I want the background of my tab to be transparent

Comment: *I want the background of my tab to be transparent* Unfortunately it cannot be set to transparent. `The background of my tab` can be set to other colors, but it's very complex：[Creating a styles.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20vMi.png) Inherited from "@style/Maui.SplashTheme" can `change The background of my tab` but it will affect textcolor of tab and ohter things. They need to be traversed to be found like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXBT3.png). -- So do you want this?

Comment: https://ibb.co/kH4Dk4N Now I changed like this. But somehow I wanted to learn the other options as well. For altering tabs, A guy referred me a nugget package names as Sharpnado.Tabs.Maui.

Comment: You can also refer to the official documetion: [Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-8.0) to get more infomation.

Answer (score 0):

Take the gray background in your picture as an example:

Create `styles.xml` file in Platforms/Android/Resources/values, and set its `Build Action` to `AndroidResource`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Maui.SplashTheme">
        <item name="android:background">#BEBEBE</item>

   </style>
</resources>
```

Change `@style/Maui.SplashTheme` to `Theme = "@style/MyTheme"` :

```cs
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme", ...)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
}
```

In your CustomShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker:

```cs
public override void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
{


   base.SetAppearance(bottomView, appearance);
    if (Shell.GetTabBarIsVisible(shellContext.Shell.CurrentPage))
    {
        var backgroundDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
        backgroundDrawable.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
        backgroundDrawable.SetCornerRadius(30);
        backgroundDrawable.SetColor(appearance.EffectiveTabBarBackgroundColor.ToPlatform());


       bottomView.SetBackground(backgroundDrawable);
       
        bottomView.SetElevation(0);


       
        var layoutParams = bottomView.LayoutParameters;
        if (layoutParams is ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams)
        {
            const int margin = 30;
            marginLayoutParams.BottomMargin = margin;
            marginLayoutParams.LeftMargin = margin;
            marginLayoutParams.RightMargin = margin;
            bottomView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
        }
        


       for (int i = 0; i < bottomView?.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            BottomNavigationMenuView? res =bottomView.GetChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationMenuView;
            if (res != null)
            {
                res.ItemIconSize = 0;
            }


           for (int j = 0;j<res?.ChildCount;j++)
            {
                var res2 =res.GetChildAt(j) as BottomNavigationItemView;
                res2?.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Black);
                
                for (int k = 0; k < res2?.ChildCount; k++)
                {
                    var res3 = res2.GetChildAt(k) as BaselineLayout;
                    res3?.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Black);


                   for (int L = 0; L < res3?.ChildCount; L++)
                    {
                        var res4 = res3.GetChildAt(k) as MaterialTextView;
                        res4?.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Black);
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
         
    }
}
```

And your appshell:

```xml
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp2.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp2"
    Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor="Black"
    Shell.TabBarTitleColor="White"
    Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor="Grey"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Title="MauiApp2" >



    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Add New">
            <ShellContent Title="Home"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
                          Route="MainPage" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Upcoming">
            <ShellContent Title="NewPage2"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage2}"
                          Route="NewPage2" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>

</Shell>
```